# GPL-compatible database of country & region names

Tags: database, php

For WordPress's sister project BuddyPress, we are looking for relatively-reputable resources that manage a list of countries and regions. Due to the WordPress OpenSource philosophy, we are only seeking GPL-compatible resources.

If no such resources exist, we could possibly consider GPL-compatible services as well.

Or there could possibly be a GlotPress-like service (see http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/dev) wherein the community contributes and maintains the database which can be downloaded via a link or API.

So far all the databases/services I have found have either been commercial or otherwise incompatible with GPL.

Answer (score 1):

It will give you just the names and a point near the center of the region (someone correct me on the location of the point if I'm wrong please), but what about GeoNames from the NGA?   Note, however, that their coverage does not include the U.S. For that, you would want the Geographic Name Information System (GNIS) from the USGS.  Link for GeoNames is:  http://earth-info.nga.mil/gns/html/ and for the GNIS:  http://geonames.usgs.gov/domestic/download_data.htm

If, on the other hand, you were looking for the polygons for countries and their regions, I'd suggest Natural Earth Data, which can be found at naturalearthdata.com.

All three data sets are in the public domain, and thus compatible with the GPL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How about geonames.org? There are also only points. License is attribution-only.